# Usage of 私的, 私用 and 私情

Tags: word-choice, usage, word-usage

In mails these are usually written when it's a personal/private matter.

But is there any difference in usage? Like in Case X you should use 私用 or in Case Y use 私情.

What would be the proper usage for each term?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

私用 is a no-adjective, 私的 is a na-adjective, and 私情 is a simple noun.

- 私用のメール means private/personal mails only in the sense of "unrelated to the business".
- 私的なメール also refers to the same thing, but it tends to have a connotation of "sensitive/secret".
- <sup>[×]</sup>私情のメール / <sup>[×]</sup>私情なメール doesn't make sense.
- 私情が入ったメール/私情のこもったメール: a subjective mail that is biased by someone's personal feelings; a (business) mail which is interfered by one's personal feelings

When a manager of a company says "Don't send private emails when you are at work", they can say both 私用のメールを出さないでください and 私的なメールを出さないでください interchangeably.

You cannot use 私用 in sentences like 「私的なメールを見られなくないので、パスワードをかけています」「サーバーが攻撃され、たくさんの人の私的な写真が流出してしまった」.

Comment: How about when used in mails like: 私用のため遅れます、私的のため遅れます、私情のため遅れます? I've seen all of these used this way.

Comment: 私用のため遅れます makes perfect sense, but other two sentences are wrong both grammatically and semantically.

Comment: I see. How about 私事都合? Would that be different from 私用?

Comment: 私事【しじ】都合 is a stiff way of saying 私用 or "for personal reasons" in formal letters.